# Paste with VIM through regular-expression replace

Tags: vim, vi

I'm using VIM's `y` command to copy some code (multiline), and want to paste it with `p`-command in some other place in the file.

However, I want to paste the copied code quickly after doing some changes to it. For example, I want to transform the copied code to uppercase (copied "hello" but pasting "HELLO").

Additional example, is to add some indentation:

Copying:

```
function hello() {
}
```

but pasting:

```
   function hello() {
   };
```

Is there some quick way to do it? With minimum commands, file/configuration changes and much better to use as standard ways/commands/frameworks to do that, as possible, as I want a solution that works in many platforms, including old *vi*, macOS's vim and more.

P.S. If there's some other built-in way, specifically to paste code with the correct indentation according to the pasting-location, I'd love to know about it as well. But, still want to know about performing random regex on copied piece of content, before pasting it (even if it's not a source-code).

Answer (score 0):

In `vim`, `'[` and `']` (line-based) or `` `[ ``, `` `] `` (character-based) are marks that identify the boundaries of the previously changed or yanked / pasted text.

So `>']` will indent-out the code in between the cursor position and the end of the pasted text after `p`.

`` gU`[ `` after `p`/`P` to uppercase the text from the cursor to the start of the paste.

Comment: There are no markers for the whole copied text? So I will be able to use it to perform regex replace

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex search and replace to change the case of a letter or word.

- `~` can flip the case of a letter, word, direction, selection etc.  e.g. move the cursor to the `h` of `hello` and type `~w` to change the whole word to `HELLO`
- `gU` doesn't flip the case, it changes the text to uppercase.   e.g. if you had `hElLo`, then move the cursor to `h` and typed `gUw`, it would become `HELLO`
- gu changes text to lowercase - e.g. move the cursor to `H` in HELLO and type `guw` to change it to `hello`.

This is only a minimal overview.  type `:help case` in `vim` for more options and details.

---

You might also want to look into vim's macro/key-mapping capabilities to automate repetitive editing tasks (`:help macro`).  I usually map `,` or `;` to whatever repetitive-but-temporary edit task I need at the moment (yes, I know they already have uses in vi but I rarely, if ever, use them. and they're both conveniently close to both each other and `.`), so I might map `,` to move to the start of the line, move forward one word, and then uppercase the word starting from the cursor:

```
:map , 0wgUw
```

After that, pressing `,` it will uppercase the second word of a line.  e.g. on a line containing `function hello() {`, it will uppercase HELLO.  It doesn't need to be perfect, it just needs to do the one little thing that would be annoying if i had to it repeatedly (in fact, it's usually the annoyance of doing the same thing more than a few times and the knowledge that I'm going to have to do it dozens or hundreds more times that motivates me to do the mapping)

And, yes, it is possible to make a macro that yanks and entire function, move the cursor, paste and indent it, then uppercase the function name.  I'm not motivated to actually do that myself right now.  I will suggest, though, breaking it into two mappings - one to search for `^function` and yank the entire thing, and the other to paste and uppercase the function name.   (stuff like this is why I like to use `,` and `;` for temporary maps...the proximity of the keys to each other is very convenient).

For stuff that I use repeatedly in more than just whatever file(s) I'm currently editing, I map it to a function key or record it in a register.  I don't do this often, because most of my tediously repetitive tasks are highly situational and specific to whatever I'm currently working on....I tend to define function key macros in my ~/.vimrc for very generic stuff like piping the current paragraph through `par` for reformatting.